# check if R df contents match, then reference another value if they do

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I have two dataframes of different lengths in R which contain dictionary entries (df2 is much longer than df1), and the second dataframe has extra frequency info that I want to add to the first. I'd like to check if the first and second dataframes have the same entries. Then, if the entries match, I need to copy the frequency info from the second df to the first.

```
df1 = data.frame(word = c("align", "amassed", "unbraid", "upturn"))
df2 = data.frame(word = c("align", "tutor", "secure", "upturn", "shout", "love"), 
                 frequency = c(2.01, 5.6, 15.4, 1.88, 0.07, 24.0))
```

I tried to do this with a for loop and a nested ifelse statement. This successfully compares the entries between the two dfs. However, instead of copying only the desired frequency values for the corresponding matching entries, it copies every frequency value in the whole df each time there is a match. I want it to only return the frequency value of the df1 entries that have matches in df2, and NA values for those that don't have matches.

Is there a better way to achieve this? I'm also open to not using for loops since I know that R is not necessarily made to work with them.

```
df1_freq = c()
for (x in df1$word) {
  ifelse (x == df2$word, 
          yes = df1_freq <- c(df1_freq, df2$frequency),
          no = df1_freq <- c(df1_freq, NA))
}


current output =  2.01  5.60 15.40  1.88  0.07 24.00    NA    NA    NA  2.01  5.60 15.40  1.88  0.07 24.00    NA
desired output = 2.01  NA  NA  1.88
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right) . Operation you describe is a left join, with `dplyr` it could look like `dplyr::left_join(df1, df2)`